# rake aborted wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the below error when I run my migration.

I am using ruby 1.8.6 version. We have developed plugins to make the ruby code compatible with Teradata. This migration is related to create a Teradata table in the backend.

My Migration file:

```
    class CreateObbPacDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    down
    DataWarehouse::PromotionsTradeData::ObbPacDetails.instance.create_table
  end

  def self.down
    DataWarehouse::PromotionsTradeData::ObbPacDetails.instance.drop_table
  end
end
```

My Model:

```
class DataWarehouse::PromotionsTradeData::ObbPacDetails < DataWarehouse::Table::Base
  has_nickname :obb_pac_details
  is_permanent_table

  has_fields :forecast_date       => "date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'",
             :areacode            => "byteint not null",
             :bpr_regn            => "char(2) not null",
             :base_product_number => "integer not null",
             :offer_start_date    => "date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' not null",
             :offer_id            => "char(9) not null",
             :offer_end_date      => "date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' not null",
             :bpr_uplift_perc     => "byteint not null"

  has_primary_key [:areacode, :bpr_regn, :base_product_number, :offer_start_date]

  collect_stats_on :areacode
  collect_stats_on :bpr_regn
  collect_stats_on :base_product_number
  collect_stats_on :offer_start_date  
  collect_stats_on [:forecast_date, :base_product_number]
```

Error Code:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20140328000102 --trace
(in /data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/app/models/data_warehouse/promotions_trade_data/obb_pac_details.rb:29:in `has_insert_statement'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/app/models/data_warehouse/promotions_trade_data/obb_pac_details.rb:29
/appl/apache/dev/development/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/appl/apache/dev/development/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/gems/require_all-1.1.0/lib/require_all.rb:81:in `require_all'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/gems/require_all-1.1.0/lib/require_all.rb:79:in `each'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/gems/require_all-1.1.0/lib/require_all.rb:79:in `require_all'
/data/bpf/rails_dev/RB-5.2-exp/vendor/gems/require_all-1.1.0/lib/require_all.rb:121:in `require_rel'
```

Comment: What's on line 29 of your model (obb_pac_details.rb) - your code above doesn't go down that far. Is it calling 'has_insert_statement'?

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, you haven't provided the table name to the migration after `DataWarehouse::PromotionsTradeData::ObbPacDetails.instance.create_table`.

As far as I know, [`create_table` expects](http://apidock.com/rails/v1.1.6/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) table name as a required parameter.

Also, I'm assuming the `down` in `def self.up` is a typo.